# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class error from EmbeddedID

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot with JPA for a simple CRUD application.
I have an `object (ObjectD)` with an `embedded ID (PrimaryKey)`, which has a composite primary key referencing the id's of two base `objects (ObjectA and ObjectB)` via a one-to-many relationship.
However, I am getting an error saying

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ObjectA.primarykeys[PrimaryKey].

This seems to be a fairly common problem, but I have tried all the suggestions in all the responses and can't seem to break through.  Assistance would be highly appreciated.

I have read through all similar questions and tried all the suggestions, including:

> - made sure the annotation is javax.persistence.Entity, and not org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
> - changing the mappedBy field on the OneToMany sides to PrimaryKey.objecta or PrimaryKey.objectb respectively
> - I am using Spring boot so I don't have a hibernate.cfg or persistence config file.  I am relying on spring boot jpa to do the necessary.

The only way I can start the ApplicationContext is to remove the OneToMany fields on ObjectA and B respectively.  But then I don't have a reference to the PrimaryKey from ObjectA and ObjectB which I need.  I know the problem relates to the OneToMany relationship, but I don't know how to solve it.

This is a diagram of what I am trying to do in the database:
[image: ORM]
The PrimaryKey class is intended to deal with the composite primary key in ObjectD. This is what I am trying to do with my class mappings to achieve the desired outcome:
[image: ORM2]

```
@Entity
public class ObjectA {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(nullable = false) private Long objectAId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objecta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PrimaryKey> primarykeys = new HashSet<PrimaryKey>();

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 200) private String name;

//constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashcode left out for brevity
}   

@Entity
public class ObjectB {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(nullable = false) private Long objectBId;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 200) private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectb", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    private Set<PrimaryKey> primaryKeys = new HashSet<PrimaryKey>();

//constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashcode left out for brevity   
}

@Embeddable
public class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinColumn(name="objectAId") 
    private ObjectA objectA;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name="objectBId") 
    private ObjectB objectB;

//constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashcode left out for brevity
}

@Entity
public class ObjectD {
    @EmbeddedId private PrimaryKey primaryKey;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 200) private String name;

//constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashcode left out for brevity
}
```

I have pasted the stacktrace below.

> 2019-10-15 11:39:06,203 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ObjectA.primarykeys[PrimaryKey]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>       at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ObjectA.primarykeys[PrimaryKey]
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1253)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:810)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:735)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1640)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1608)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
>       ... 40 common frames omitted
>   2019-10-15 11:39:06,204 ERROR [main] org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@7193666c] to prepare test instance [hysan.test.integrationtests.demo.service.DIntegrationTest@2bb41f5c]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@OneToMany` cannot be applied to `@Embeddable`, only to `@Entity`.

In other words you cannot write this:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "objecta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<PrimaryKey> primarykeys = new HashSet<PrimaryKey>();
```

If it's embeddable - embed it!

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, that's very useful.  I have been staring at this for too long now so am probably missing something very obvious here, but how then do I get hold of the collection of PrimaryKeys from ObjectA or ObjectB (ie bi-directional relationship)? I want to be able to interogate a PrimaryKey for what its ObjectA and ObjectB are (which is fine), but I also want to be able to ask the ObjectA object which PrimaryKey's it is part of or which PrimaryKeys the ObjectB is part of. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Well, there is a bit of a mess in your declarations. Let's ignore the PrimaryKey for a moment. You say that A is 1-many with B AND B is 1-many with A. So either this is a mistake or you have a many-many relationship. So who holds a reference to whom? Can you describe your tables?

Comment: I am obviously not understanding the way it should be done because I don't see how I have made A is 1-many with B AND B is 1-many with A. That is certainly not my intention.  I have added a diagram to the original post to describe it

Comment: According to the diagram you have a classic ManyToMany relationship (for each A there can be >1 B AND for each Bs there can be >1 As). There are 2 options to map it:

- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many
- There is an advanced option to map ObjectD as an entity (not embeddable)

Since you have userID inside ObjectD, you probably need a second option...

So you need to have `OneToMany` from ObjectD to each A & B and `ManyToOne` from A & B to D.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, you are spot-on.  I was using the wrong pattern.  Much appreciated!